# How do you reference data from different formview (ASP.NET)

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio, formview

I'm a still new to the whole creating a website please understand and explain in simple terms.

Ok, so there's a formview called FormView1 and another formview called User. In FormView1 I have a data called CoinEarn and the other formview data called CurrentCoin (from different formview)

I want to update CurrentCoin through a session so I could put it on my update SQL (by Session("CurrentCoin") = CurrentCoin + CoinEarn) after clicking a button (which is placed inside FormView1 template). In the code I gave the button the command name "complete".

Since CurrentCoin is from a different SQL and formview I need to reference/call up the specific data (CurrentCoin) so I can make the session.

I'm not sure if my thought/solution on this problem is correct or not (by calling up data or make a session to update CurrentCoin) but the main objective is to make CurrentCoin += CoinEarn after clicking a button.

Please help me! I've been trying to find the answer but it's too complicated to understand in proper websites.

```
Protected Sub FormView1_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As FormViewCommandEventArgs) Handles FormView1.ItemCommand
    If e.CommandName = "complete" Then


        Dim row As FormViewRow = FormView1.Row

        Dim TaskstatusLabel As Label = CType(row.FindControl("TaskStatusLabel"), Label)
        Dim what As String = TaskstatusLabel.Text

        Dim TaskCoin As Label = CType(row.FindControl("CoinEarnLabel"), Label)
        Dim Coin As String = TaskCoin.Text


        ''Session("CurrentcoinSession") = Coin + CurrentCoin 
        Dim TaskstatusLabelID As Label = CType(row.FindControl("TaskIDLabel"), Label)
        Dim whatTaskID As String = TaskstatusLabelID.Text
        Session("TaskIDSession") = whatTaskID

        If TaskstatusLabel.Text = "Complete" Then
            Session("TaskStatusSession") = "Incomplete"
            ElseIf TaskstatusLabel.Text = "Incomplete" Then
                Session("TaskStatusSession") = "Complete"
        End If

        SqlDsStatus1.Update()     
        FormView1.DataBind()

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of session CurrentCoin optional:
Session("CurrentCoin") = ((Label)MyFormView.FindControl("lblCurrentCoin")).Text

Session("CurrentcoinSession") = Coin + Session("CurrentCoin")

[get values from a form view](https://forums.asp.net/t/1122406.aspx?Get%20values%20from%20FormView%20Control)

Comment: Thank you, for your time. I got it to work now. It's actually not that bad, it's just that someone else helped me wrote that code so I only understand half of it . But the 'get values from a form view' helped me understand it fully now :)